# Reserve space for job advertisement before loading

Tags: feature-request, design, advertising

I'm not sure it's only me or all the others, but I've suffered from clicking on the job related advertisement on the right pane on SO accidentally. It's mainly because when I open the SO page and click on <kbd>Questions</kbd> on the top bar, that part of the page is not always (almost never) loaded, and the content immediately below is the "Related Tags", which I'll nearly always click on. By the time I scroll down there, the advertisement bar is ready and most of time I have a great chance of clicking on the ads.

I think it's totally acceptable to have ads, but could you please just reserve some space for them before they're fully loaded. Or is there not any one else who also suffers from this? (Even a duplicate?)

Comment: +1 me too this happens all the time to me

Comment: Yes! Space should always be reserved for elements before they load. It drives me crazy how many sites make me click on the wrong thing because an ad loaded just as I clicked. Stack Exchange should be better than that.

Comment: I agree that this should be a priority, but one possible consideration for why this hasn't been done yet is that not all ads are the same size.

Comment: I'd label this as a [tag:bug] rather than feature request.

Comment: Please do this for all ads! I often find myself flagging obvious spam questions before the page loads. However, most spam questions have a link at the bottom of the post, which is just in the wrong spot, so when the ad loads, I end up clicking the spam link rather than the flag button! Reserving space for the ads would help out a lot.

Comment: What "Questions" bottom you are talking about?

Comment: Does this site use jquery? Isn't this probably a consequence of which code is the backbone of the page and which is brought in modularly via jquery or something similar? Might not be the easiest/most desirable fix from a maintainability standpoint.